Is it wrong to say that the distance locally approximates the metric in a manifold?
I am doing some data analysis where I use the Riemannian distances between matrices in a manifold (Symmetric Positive Definite matrices).
In my application, the formula for the Riemannian metric giving rise to the distance is connected to a well-known formula in the field. I want to tell the non-math audience that the geometry we are using is connected to this well known formula.
The issue is that my work revolves around distances, which are intuitive, and I don't want to try to explain to the audience what a Riemannian metric is, which will take much time and not add much in this presentation. So, my thought to circunvent introducing Riemannian metrics was to show the formula for the Riemannian metric, and say that locally the Riemannian distance approximates this formula. This seems related to saying that, locally, the Riemannian distance approximates the Riemannian metric.
Technically, the statement seems wrong, or at least extremely vague, since the metric function and the distance function don't even have the same input space. However, I am wondering whether the statement is also completely misguided even to use in the context explained above, of quickly and intuitively introducing what a metric is to a non-expert audience. I am not expert enough to be confident that the statement would be completely wrong, although it rings intuitively reasonable.

This formula justifies your intuition:https://mathoverflow.net/questions/393703/taylor-expansion-of-the-square-of-the-distance-function-on-a-riemannian-manifold

Thanks, that seems very useful!

FWIW. Consider this quick and dirty approximation to the truth: a  Riemannian manifold is a geometrical space that can be  modeled locally using a chunk of ordinary Euclidean space  that has been  smoothly stretched and distorted like a chunk of putty. The stretching of  the Euclidean space distorts our notion of distance: small  concentric  spheres   are transformed to objects that tend (in the limit) to perfect ellipsoids. The equation for each ellipsoid is described by a quadratic form (a symmetric matrix called the Riemannian metric).
